# Taking a Photo in Fragment

Tags: android, android-intent, camera, fragment

I added two fragments into android.R.id.content. In my last added fragment, I am trying to take a photo. I implemented onActivityResult for this fragment. However after saving photo, it executes both fragments and crashes.

After taking photo and pressing onto save, why does it execute both of the fragments?

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getActivity()
                        .getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                transaction.add(android.R.id.content, newFragment).commit();
```

Comment: Maybe you put your code? What method are you using when you navigate from one fragment to another?

Comment: Please post your code and/or the stack trace logs.

Comment: I am adding new fragment onto android.R.id.content. Because I need to go back to previous fragment.

Comment: When I remove the first fragment before committing transaction, it works fine. However, when there is two fragment in android.R.id.content, it executes both fragments after returning from taking photo activity.

Answer (score 0):

You can open the camera directly like this:

```
 private boolean safeCameraOpenInView(View view) {
        boolean qOpened = false;
        releaseCameraAndPreview();
        mCamera = getCameraInstance();
        qOpened = (mCamera != null);
        mPreview = new CameraPreview(getActivity().getBaseContext(), mCamera);
        FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout)            view.findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
        preview.addView(mPreview);
        return qOpened;
 }
```

And take a photo inside a fragment.